# Problem setting font size when font family is set to Courier in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, size

I seem to have trouble setting the font size of the text of a legend item when the font family is set to Courier.

```
legendItem.setStyle("fontFamily", "Courier");
legendItem.setStyle("fontSize", 7);
```

**doesn't work.**

But:

```
legendItem.setStyle("fontFamily", "Verdana");
legendItem.setStyle("fontSize", 7);
```

does!

Is this a **Flex** bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think the courier font dows not exist in your system.

If exists then use embeded fonts

[Embedded Fonts](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried this and I got the following error: Unable to transcode C:/WINNT/Fonts/coure.ttf